# How to detect color from PDF Python

Tags: python, pdf

Is there any way, in Python, of automatically detect the colors in a certain area of a PDF and either translate them to RGB or compare them to the legend and then get the color?

Comment: Maybe you could convert the PDF into a picture format (BMP for instance) and analyze that.

Answer (score 3):

[Felipe](https://stackoverflow.com/users/754254/felipe)'s approach didn't work for me, but I came up with this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- Encoding: UTF-8 -*-

import minecart

colors = set()

with open("file.pdf", "rb") as file:
    document = minecart.Document(file)
    page = document.get_page(0)
    for shape in page.shapes:
        if shape.fill:
            colors.add(shape.fill.color.as_rgb())

for color in colors: print color
```

This will print a neat list of all unique RGB values in the first page of your document (you could extend it to all pages, of course).

Answer (score 1):

Depending on where you want to extract the information from, you can use [`minecart`](https://github.com/felipeochoa/minecart). It has really robust support for colors and allows easy conversion to RGB. Though you can't input a coordinate and get the color value there, if you are trying to get color information from a shape you could do something like the following:

```py
import minecart
doc = minecart.Document(open("my-doc.pdf", "rb"))
page = doc.get_page(0)
BOX = (.5 * 72,  # left bounding box edge
       9 * 72,   # bottom bounding box edge
       1 * 72,   # right bounding box edge
       10 * 72)  # top bounding box edge
for shape in page.shapes:
    if shape.check_in_bbox(BOX):
        r, g, b = shape.fill.color.as_rgb()
        # do stuff with r, g, b
```

[Disclaimer: I'm the author of `minecart`]

Comment: getting this erro KeyError: 'DeviceN' @Felipe